# Propagate validation from Model to View with Catel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I am working on a program using Catel's MVVM (4.0.0) implementation. I have a model class which as some business logic - it must observe a rule regarding one of it's properties values.

For example, let say I have a `Trap` class which has a `TargetValue` and a `CurrentValue` properties. For this class there is a rule that must enforce that the `TargetValue` property can only be less then or equal (<=) `CurrentValue`. (The `CurrentValue` is updated via some events in the system).

The traps are exposed to the user (I have a VM which holds a list of such traps and is bound to a data grid in the UI) where she can change `TargetValue`.

Initially I though to create a VM to wrap the `Trap` object instance and enforce the rule there but since the rule is actually related more to the model (or business logic, that is, I may need the same rule everywhere I use `Trap` class) I thought it better to implement it in the property setter for `TargetValue` (where I will check the validity of the new value and either reset or not change the underlying field value).

So supposedly I do it in the setter (is that even a correct implementation?) - is there a way to notify the VM (or UI directly) that there was a violation (for example by setting cell border color or something)?

I thought that maybe I can use the `RaisePropertyChanging` in collaboration with `RaisePropertyChanged` that `ObservableObject` exposes though it seems cumbersome.

Is there a proper way for such a pattern?

Thanks,

Tomer

Comment: [Catel.MVVM Validation example](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Validation+example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion regarding Catel's capabilities it seems that going through "regular" validation flow would not do the trick here due to the order of operations:

- Property Setter
- ValidateFields
- Error info is ready for VM

What the solution should be is as follows:

- The `CurrentValue` property setter should be private so that it cannot be bound to (either directly or through the VM by using decorations etc
- Add to the `Trap` class `IDataErrorInfo` (or `INotifyDataErrorInfo`) implementation
- Implement a `SetCurrentValue` function which validates data and only sets it if legal. In case not, invoke `IDataErrorInfo` mechanism.
- In the UI - bind to the function and not property (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348824(v=vs.110).aspx)

This approach should answer the requirements above - the property value is never invalid in any use case but still it is possible to coordinate with the UI.

Comment: What is the "regular validation flow?" Call Model.Validate(true) then save changes to the db/file if there are no errors?

Answer (score 2):

You should not validate in the setter because the setter is responsible for setting the value of the object. Assuming that the model uses INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo (or INotifyDataErrorInfo), you can do big things with Catel.

For example, in the ModelBase you can override the ValidateFields or ValidateBusinessRules or even apply a custom validator to your models. Then the ModelBase will automatically implement the change notifications and validation interfaces for you.

Next, the VM contains the trap, for example the vm below (note that this example uses Catel.Fody):

```
public class MyTrapViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyTrapViewModel(Trap trap)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => trap);

        Trap = trap;
    }

    [Model]
    [Expose("CurrentValue")]
    [Expose("TargetValue")]
    private Trap Trap { get; set; }
}
```

In this example, you define the `Trap` property as model. This means that Catel will watch it for notifications and map the properties on the view model to the model and vice versa. Now comes the cool thing: it doesn't only map the property values, it maps the validation rules as well. This means that this view model would be sufficient for your views and you can implement the validation in the models.

Comment: I am using `ObservableObject` as base for the model class in order to keep things light. From what I see, this class doesn't support the require mechanisms. 
I may change it (though I am reluctant due to "overhead" but I think (correct me if I am wrong) that the validation may flag an error but still the underlying value will be changed - or does it "cancel" the update completely? 
In case it does not cancel this solution would not work for me as other threads my "watch" this (trap) object and could possibly use the illegal value.

Comment: You can still use ObservableObject, but if you want validation, you  a) need to write this yourself or b) use Catel which has been optimized over the years. It's up to you.

Comment: I have no doubt that Catel's code is better than any code I'd write. My concern was about the actual sequence of events - would using the intrinsic validation would solve my issue - if there is a validation error - does it prevent from actually updating the property?

Let say I use ValidateFields - I check the property value in the function for the condition and I can raise an error/warning - but it is already to late because the condition is violated...

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can only validate (and keep the validation state) if the property can actually be set. So you can set the property, but then the model becomes invalid (this is normal behavior).

Comment: Thanks @Geert for being so responsive and informative. Your input (and Catel) is very helpful in developing MVVM! In any case, for this use case  this solution would not work since the trap instance should never be invalid. It is also "monitored" by background services and if activate between the time property is set and validate will result in errors. It could be my design... I think in this case I should not use property but a function to set the value in which case I can do validation and also implement `IDataErrorInfo`.